# How can I find the range of a field covered by each page of a paginated set?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have a model `Task`(`id`, `start_date`, `end_date`, `description`).  I use Paginator like

```
    $this->Paginator->settings = array(
        'Task'=>array(
            'contain'=>$contain,
            'limit'=> $limit,
            'conditions'=>$conditions,
            'order'=>'Task.start_date ASC',
            'page'=> $page,
    ));
```

What I'm after is to be able to know the range of `start_date` covered by each page of the paged set. Instead of page numbers (i.e. in view generated by `$this->Paginator->numbers()`) I'd like to create links like "2 weeks ago" and "Today" that jump to the page containing the first `Task` with `start_date` > NOW()-14Days, for example.

I fully understand I could alter my `$conditions` and set a range on the `start_date`, but I want the whole set.

Open to other ideas on how to achieve the same result, or any pointers in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up running my search twice, once paginated, once not.  I then went through the unpaged results

```
$pgStarts = array();    
$pgCounter = 1;

foreach($tasks as $k => $task){
    if(($k % $limit) == 0){
        $pgStarts[$pgCounter] = $task['Task']['start_time'];
        $pgCounter++;
    }
}
```

Once I had the array of start dates for each page I could easily change the way the paging numbers were labeled. I was even able to break down the key event day by hour (most tasks are on this day).

[image: If today were Feb 2. Also, vertical align in Twitter Bootstrap is killing me]

I'm happy with the result, as I think it gives the paging more context.  I'll continue to look for a better way of doing it, but this will do for now.

Answer (score 0):

You need to calculate the records before and after the given start date of your condition and then divide it by the number of records per page to get the page it is on.

However, this is not very user friendly, instead I would do this:

Pass your start date and range in the URL and based on the passed values build your query that you then use within your pagination settings.

```
/something/index?range=last-two-weeks
```

And check for the range value and do a switch for that value to set the right conditions. This will directly filter only the records the user is really interested in by a clear to understand URL.